# Sync tables from Host1 to Host2 with over 50 million rows?

Tags: mysql, replication, load-balancing

I apologize first for using Sync in the title, that may be the wrong term. I am using MySQL, but can switch to Postgress or other open source platform.

I have a service that when people subscribe to we receive a lot of data from them, around ~60,000 rows that gets split up across multiple tables using a http endpoint processed by php. After the initial sync, we only receive incremental updates.

Looking at server load, we became concerned that it would become an issue as we added more and more customers and so setup a separate server that would handle all the http requests, parse the data and place it in the right tables. As load increased, we could then section off customers to other identical servers.

The question is what should I do to effectively replicate the data on those finished tables over to the production server (same network)? I could setup triggers, but that would result in tens of thousands of individual connection requests for each insert.

If I setup were to setup mirroring / master-slave, I want it to ignore all existing data because I wouldn't want it to try comparing things that have already been sent on a regular basis since that could grow to 50 million rows quickly.

It would be more like :

```
SELECT @rowcount:=COUNT(*) FROM production.database.table1;
INSERT INTO production.table1 SELECT * FROM workhorse.database.table1 where `id` >@rowcount;
```

Something this simple could be run once a minute or so I would think and cut down on individual connections. I realize this is kind of messy since COUNT and ID aren't locked together, but it gets the idea across. Also, I don't know a way to run the query on a remote server.

Are there any tools/commands that would make quick work of this?

Comment: What database are you using? Have you looked into ETL tools?

Comment: So sorry, I should have mentioned I was using MySQL, but can switch to Postgress or other open source platform. I will look into ETL tools, but would love an open source solution. It always makes me nervous when companies don't share pricing - but want to sign you up today :)

Comment: Fears justified: $1,000-$15,000/month  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12585791

Comment: @Alan - [edit] your question with details in your comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Master-Slave (and various other forms of replication) provide keeping two (or more) hosts in sync continually.  No ETL process needed.

Splitting the client processes and MySQL into separate servers is a good first step.

Putting different customers on different "shards" provides 'infinite' scalability in that dimension.  You would need some form of proxy or home-grown directing to get from a client to the necessary server.

Ingesting 60K rows is pretty trivial unless, of course, the data format is always something different.  At that point, I might contract a programmer who knows Perl (or other tool) to crank out ingestion scripts.  (Years ago, I did such with news feeds.)

Does 50M rows at 60K per customer mean you have 1000 customers?

I would suggest you use sharding do deal with excessive write traffic and disk space.  And use Slaves for excessive read traffic.

It is a never-ending pain to try to perfect "sync" scripts.

Comment: Great ideas Rick, I am concerned about the master-slave scenario having too many small transactions as time goes on. I setup a federated db config which is allowing me to batch process them on a cron job, but I haven't figured out how to deal with a situation where the source data changes, such as if a customer phone# was updated. Currently working on finding a way to run a nested update query using the `updated_at` field.

Comment: Do the numbers.  How many updates per day will you have?  Number of active customers times average number of updates/inserts/deletes in 24 hours.  MySQL can probably handle 1 million/day "out of the box".  If you need more, we can talk about batching, ssds, slaves, sharing, and other techniques that can probably get you 10M/day with minimal effort.

Comment: Thanks Rick, each customer will have 10,000-80,000 records depending on how long they have been in business. On a daily basis they should generate an additional 50ish inserts. I was noticing a server load of 0.8 with only 2 customers syncing which lasted about 30 minutes - here I mean the big initial sync. I haven't launched the product to the public yet, but imagine when I do I could have 100+ sign up and want to do the initial sync on the same day. I am trying to figure out how to process the data without it slowing down the user experience on the web server.

Comment: Some of that server load is naturally the apache service parsing incoming JSON data, the rest is mysql. I was thinking it would be better to do federated like on my other thread you commented on to let the server "rest" and focus on web traffic and then do a surge sync, but I didn't realize it was much slower. I just found I can do a delayed sync on the master-slave relationship, which might be better. Going to do some youtube to figure out how I want to develop the relationships.

Comment: 30 minutes to do a sync?  That sounds unreasonable.  What code do you use for that?  Single-row `INSERTs`?  Batch inserts?  `LOAD DATA INFILE`?  The last is what you _should_ use.

Comment: Pepper the code with timings -- you need to understand how much time is spent in JSON, how much in MySQL.  Consider a separate process to turn JSON into CSV.  _This_ may be the real solution.

Comment: How could you make use of a M-S delay?

Comment: Data comes from a windows service that queries mysql, then sends over https data as json in groups of 500 records at a time. It waits for an acknowledgement that data was received and sends next set. Each customer has about 100MB of transferred data on first sync. It contains lists of their customers, contact info, appointments, appointment details. It is years worth of their appointments at a rate of 15-20 per day for around 3,000-8,000 unique customers of theirs. As you say, I do need to find out how much time is spent in each operation and try converting to CSV first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64766/discussion-between-alan-and-rick-james).